# How to: CTRL+ Click -> Go to Definition in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How to set Visual Studio 2008, so when I click left mouse button while holding CTRL it triggers action "Go To Definition" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to set this from the options. You could write your addin, but this is too much pain for something like this.

Comment: It is implemented in VS 2013. and there are extensions for earlier versions as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking because you have seen others use this functionality, then it is likely they had the add-in [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) installed — this is one of the many features provided.

Comment: Actually, I use his functionality myself in one of PHP IDEs.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think this can be done.

But there is an alternative shortcut F12 (In VB mode i guess)

You can check also check the shortcuts from Tools->Options->Keyboard